# Empty/half filled table scraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, dataframe, html-table, rvest

This is the site:

http://en.openei.org/apps/USURDB/rate/view/53bedfaf5257a37b15b4ba01

Aim: Trying to fetch all the tables included empty ones.

Problem: I am not getting any table as on the site.

*For 1st table*: Can dots be stored in DF as character or any other data type ?

*For 2nd table*: (Time of Use Demand Charge Structure)

```
shtml <-html(http://en.openei.org/apps/USURDB/rate/view/53bedfaf5257a37b15b4ba01#2__Demand, encoding = 'UTF-8')
shtml %>% 
  html_nodes('#flat_demand_strux_table') %>%
  html_table(h=TRUE,trim=FALSE,fill=TRUE)
```

I tried `html_tag` after getting `html_Tag(x) == 'Table'` error
after which i got:

> Error in UseMethod("html_nodes","html_tables") : no applicable method for html_nodes/html_tables...

For both i tried `html_text` and then converting it to data frame but it gives only one big row with all data in continuation like:

`Period Tier Max kVA Usage Rate $/kVA Adjustments $/kVA 11 10 36.61 Â  Â  2 15 49.05 Â  Â  3 20 55.47 Â  Â   4 25 61.89 Â  Â 5 30 67.98.`

Tried with different encodings but no results.

Where's the issue?

It is the first of my requirements for further processing and am stuck here only.

Comment: You aren't getting any tables since there aren't any `<table>`s. There _are_ _many_ `<div>`s, hence why `html_table()` isn't working. you'll have to target each element differently and manually build the data frame(s).

Comment: ohh! thanks for the quick and correct response, but selecting every element will be tedious and I have to run it in a loop for every web page(Utilty) which may result in heavy time/load. Is there any other option.

Answer (score 3):

I would use the XML package if I were you.  I still haven't been convinced to make the move to rvest.  My start at the solution is not perfect but it should work.  Generally I use a Chrome extension called SelectorGadget and then I use regular expressions to clean up the text.  If you are hitting multiple URLs but doing the same stuff on each page I recommend using the foreach package to loop through each page.  There is an option to remove urls that had errors and that is really convenient

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'http://en.openei.org/apps/USURDB/rate/view/53bedfaf5257a37b15b4ba01#2__Demand'

doc = htmlParse(url)

# - xpath taken from SelectorGadget
gg <- getNodeSet(doc, '//*[(@id = "demand_rate_strux_table")]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "strux_view_cell", " " ))]')

# - Get the values from the nodes
Values = sapply(gg, xmlValue)

# - put in table form
Table <- t(matrix(Values, nrow = 5))

# - remove paragraph breaks and 2 - 55 spaces in a row
Names <- gsub('\n|[ ]{2,55}','',Table[1,])

FinalTable <-
data.frame(
  X1 = as.numeric(gsub("Â", '0', gsub('[ ]{1,4}', '', Table[-1,1])))
  ,X2 = as.numeric(gsub("Â ", NA, Table[-1,2]))
  ,X3 = as.numeric(gsub("Â ", NA, Table[-1,3]))
  ,X4 = as.numeric(gsub("Â ", NA, Table[-1,4]))
  ,X5 = as.numeric(gsub("Â ", NA, Table[-1,5]))
) %>%
  # - Fix the period so it is tidy :)
  mutate(
    X1 = cummax(X1)
  )

# - Add in column names
colnames(FinalTable) = Names
```

Comment: Wow! that really works JackStat, I tried with XML also but didn't use getNode because from the start i was thinking it is a table.

Comment: I am glad that works for you.  Maybe I am old school but I have used XML for a while and I like the flexibility.  Are there several pages that are the same that you need to scrape?  If there are I recommend going to a page that has all of the links (if it exists) and scraping those into a vector and then you can use foreach to go through each one and build a large data.frame out of it.  Happy Scraping!